# Create "inspect element" functionality in the browser

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a project where the user should be able to hover over / click arbitrary HTML elements, and the selected element is recorded programmatically. The desired functionality is similar to Chrome / Firefox's "inspect element" functionality.

Before rolling my own, has anyone found a good open source, cross-browser implementation?

Thanks!

Comment: Firebug? http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Comment: I think he's meaning "firebug" inside webpage, not on browser.

Comment: Exactly - firebug light in the webpage in any browser: http://jsfiddle.net/6dVkW/

Comment: @BrandonBoone: jsFiddle even has a switch in the options for that: http://jsfiddle.net/6dVkW/1/ :-)

Comment: @Bergi - No WAY! Never even saw that before. Ha, here I thought I'd done something clever.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:
https://github.com/toolness/webxray

You would need to fork the project and modify it to fit your needs, but the "inspection" functionality already works.

You can see how it is used by Mozilla in here:
https://goggles.webmaker.org/en-US/